# Running a task in windows service

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, windows-services

I am making a windows service and one of its task is to ask for a free disk space every 1 hour, I know how to get the free space when the service starts but how to check for it every 1 hour?

Comment: Ok, then I've undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Timer` like [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();    
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);

timer.Interval = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour
timer.Enabled = true;

...

private static void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // check disk space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start thread:

```
while(true){
  getFreeSpace();
  Sleep(3600*1000);
};
```